# Multi-Tenant ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, owin

I am trying to create a multi-tenant application using ASP.NET MVC.

In order to determine which entities in a given table to use, I need to parse the domain request in order to determine which site to return to the User.  Where is the best place to do this calculation and store it?  It needs to be a Session/Request type variable (as opposed to an application one) - but is there a standard method for doing this?  Can OWIN be used for Session-level variables?

Comment: Why are the database tables different?  Shouldn't the application use a static schema and the data relevant to the logged-in user would be derived by fields in those tables?  For example, a User may have a ClientID, and each entity type may have a ClientOwnerID.  So any request for data would filter on that ID.  Each request has a user context, so Session doesn't seem necessary here.

Comment: You are correct - for instance, there is an "Posts" table that contains Posts created on a site.  Each post has a SiteID foreign key which refers to the Site that it was created on.  That SiteID refers to the Sites table with domain information (e.g. www.awesome.com).  When a user requests awesome.com, the idea is to only deliver content created on that site.

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like a global action filter to avoid duplicating Tenant logic all over the place?

Comment: I'm not sure what a global action filter is - how does that work?  Basically I have implemented an IRepository framework to access the datastore and the base class of the IRepository filters the results of queries based on the context of the web application (i.e. which site is being viewed)

Answer (score 0):

```
Application_BeginRequest
```

is a natural candidate for this and we mostly do it there. Then, the `Items` container (which is of request scope) is used to store this so that it is further available down the processing pipeline.